# How to use a YAML config file in Silex Framework

Tags: php, yaml, symfony, silex

Is it possible to configure a Silex Application with YAML config files? I bet yes, but how is it done correctly? For instance I want to use different configurations according to the environment, like config.dev.yml and config.prod.yml.

The config file should contain parameters for the app itself and for the registered extensions/services.

Example:

```
// Debug flag should be set in the config file
$app['debug'] = true;

// Extension options should also be set in config file
$app->register(new Silex\Extension\TwigExtension(), array(
    'twig.path'       => __DIR__.'/views',
    'twig.class_path' => __DIR__.'/vendor/Twig/lib',
));
```

Do I have to parse the YAML file by myself and set the parameters accordingly or is there a more "magic" way to do this?

Comment: Just found this extension on GitHub: https://github.com/tyaga/LoadConfigExtension/blob/master/LoadConfigExtension.php

Comment: That doesn't set anything on your app/container though. It just creates an `$app['config']` service.

Comment: Ok, but it just did what I was looking for... a way to load a yml config file. Nothing magical here, but works ;) (Be careful when using this extension, it uses the "old" ExtensionInterface. This has changed in the new Silex version)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First of all, add the Symfony Yaml component to your **composer.json**

```
"symfony/yaml": "2.1.*@dev",
```

Use the right version choosing directly from the packagist page: https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/yaml

Now, you can add the **deralex YamlConfigProvider**, a simple and useful Silex provider. Add it to your **composer.json**:

```
"deralex/yaml-config-service-provider": "1.0.x-dev"
```

Here the official github page: https://github.com/deralex/YamlConfigServiceProvider

Here the packagist page: https://packagist.org/packages/deralex/yaml-config-service-provider

**UPDATE**

Install the dependencies with `./composer.phar update` command and finally add these lines to your app file:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app->register(new DerAlex\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider(__DIR__ . '/settings.yml'));
```

Now, for example, you can do this:

**settings.yml**

```
database:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: localhost
    dbname: database_name
    user: root
    password: password
    charset: utf8
```

**index.php**

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => $app['config']['database']
));
```

Comment: Do you know if there is similar extension to load a PHP config file?

Comment: @Fractaliste try https://github.com/igorw/ConfigServiceProvider it speaks php, json, yaml, and toml

Comment: It isn't needed to require `symfony/yaml` in the own *composer.json* because it is already required by `deralex/yaml-config-service-provider` ;-)

Comment: I know que question is old, but the `"deralex/yaml-config-service-provider"` is not compatible with the last version of the `"symfony/yaml"`.
The use of the symfony/yaml was enought to me

Comment: An active-ish fork of ConfigServiceProvider with Silex 2.0 support can be found at: https://github.com/reva2/ConfigServiceProvider

Answer (score 3):

This package in the answer does not work for Silex 2.0 that is why I've created package that works for Silex 2.0 and Symfony/Yaml 3.1. Maybe someone looking for this answer will find it useful

https://packagist.org/packages/rpodwika/yaml-config-service-provider

to use run command

```
composer require rpodwika/yaml-config-service-provider
```

or add

```
"rpodwika/yaml-config-service-provider" : "dev-master"
```

to your composer.json

github link https://github.com/rpodwika/yaml-config-service-provider

to use:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Rpodwika\Silex\YamlConfigServiceProvider("settings.yml"));

echo $app['config']['database']['driver'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The LoadConfigExtension described by @fbrandel (above in comments) allows you to **share** the yml loader config service.