# Adding Symfony Yaml To Silex

Tags: symfony1, yaml, silex

I am looking to add symfony's yaml component to Silex however I am having issues with adding the 5.3 version.  Adding the none namespaced version works fine but I would rather have the namespaced version from https://github.com/symfony/Yaml.  This is my service provider:

```
public function register(Application $app)
{
    if (isset($app['classPath'])) {
        $app['autoloader']->registerNamespace('Symfony\Component\Yaml', $app['classPath']);
    }
}
```

But when I do this is code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
Yaml::load(__DIR__ . '/../configuration/application.yml');
```

I receive the error of:

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml' not found in
>   /mnt/hgfs/silex/web/index.php on line 20

Full Correct Answer:
gregoire made a comment about registering the Symfony namespace, not the Symfony\Comonent\Yaml so I basically recreated the directory structure for the namespace and registed the root of the to the Symfony namespace and that works great.

Comment: you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486599/how-to-use-a-yaml-config-file-in-silex-framework

Comment: That talks about adding the non namespaced version of Yaml which I have already implemented successfully.  Like I said I would rather have the namespaced version on Yaml for consistency sake (everything else is namespaced).  If there is no way to include the namespaced Yaml with silex, then I guess I will have to use the older version.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to register the Symfony namespace (and not Symfony\Component\Yaml)?

Comment: @gregoire You are correct.  Post an answer saying that so I can give you credit for the correct answer.

Comment: @ryanzec You can answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that silex is using composer, I am just using composer to include it.